# Add Parameters to a Request

Tags: android, http-post, httprequest, android-volley

I'm trying to send a `POST` [Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) to my server which returns a `JSONObject`, however it requires parameters in this long string form:

*client_id=`client_id`&client_secret=`client_secret`&grant_type=password&username=`username`&password=`password`*

I've been trying to figure out how to do this, however every tutorial or answer similar to this uses the depreciated `HTTPClient`, etc. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClient` was depricated since API level 22

Use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead, examples are [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/). You can also read this [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) to know more.

I'd recommend using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) as it makes managing `JSON` requests into [`POJOs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)
easier.

Comment: Like I said in my question, Android Studio (and other sources) are telling me that HttpClient and HttpPost are depreciated. Are they lying?

Comment: @MatthewSteinhardt sorry I read the question the wrong way. Check for the edit

Comment: major fail from my part :P sorry.

Comment: no worries, your revised answered worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: I hope you used retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
 public JSONObject getJSONObject(String url, List<NameValuePair> parameters) {

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
   /* httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");*/
    httpPost.addHeader("api_key", mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
        response = mHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        for (NameValuePair params : parameters) {
            Log.d("params:", params.toString());
        }
        Log.d("url:", url);
        Log.d("EntityUtils", jsonResponse);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        return jsonObject;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

and call this maethod like:

```
 public String setCricketInfo(String userId, String role, String battingStyle) {
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(mContext.getString(R.string.role_json), role));
    JSONObject jsonObject = this.getJSONObject(BASE_URL, parameters);
    try {
        return jsonObject.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

now being able to send requist to remote and get responce as Json
enjoy your code:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add("client_id", client_id);
params.add("client_secret", client_secret);
params.add("grant_type", password);
params.add("username", username);
params.add("password", password);

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://server.com", URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8"), handler, handler);
```